# JavaScript for vs forEach

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach

In [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/dkrychylskyy/yzvb61qx/) in the case of `forEach` we can get the current value, in the case of `for` we get the last value of the array. How does the connection between a button and the current value in the array work?

```js
var arr = [{ name: "Model S" },
{ name: "Model X" }, { name: "Model 3" }];
var brElt = document.createElement("br");
arr.forEach(function (el) {
    var btnElt = document.createElement("button");
    btnElt.textContent = "Ok";
    btnElt.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.target.textContent = el.name;
        e.target.style.color = "blue";

    })
    document.getElementById("contenu").appendChild(btnElt);
    document.getElementById("contenu").appendChild(brElt);
});

for (var i in arr) {
    var btnElt = document.createElement("button");
    btnElt.textContent = "Ok";
    btnElt.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.target.textContent = arr[i].name;
        e.target.style.color = "green";

    })
    document.getElementById("contenu").appendChild(btnElt);
    document.getElementById("contenu").appendChild(brElt);
};
```

```html
<div id="contenu"></div>
```

Comment: Your question is like comparing while and for.

Comment: There's no code in your question.

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572) anyway!

Comment: @ArthurGuiot `forEach` creates a closure, but `for` does not. They aren't always interchangeable (as this question demonstrates).

Comment: Bind the index argument so that it's copied!
        btnElt.addEventListener("click", function (index, e) {
            e.target.textContent = arr[index].name;
            e.target.style.color = "green";
    
        }.bind(null, i))

Comment: The connection between button and array value is via the `el` and `i` variables, and their scope widely differs between `for (var …)` and `forEach`

Comment: @4castle No, that’s not what I wanted to say. I’m simply saying that these functions are pretty different. The comparison with while is not an answer to the question, but simply a way of saying that they are different

Answer (score -1):

You're getting the last value of the array because `i` has a value of `2` as soon as that loop finishes running, and it still has that value when the click event is triggered.